# Load xml with xsl using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have 0 knowledge of javascript but I need a quick fix to make this work. I was given the block of code before. It works but only in IE. I need one that works for all browsers. Can I get an easy copy and paste code to work because I know nothing about Javascript nor much about xml. It works currently with the income.xml file and ENG_Template.xsl file being in the directory with this html file but only with IE.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
// Load XML 
var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = false
xml.load("income.xml")

// Load the XSL
var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xsl.async = false
xsl.load("ENG_Template.xsl")

// Transform
document.write(xml.transformNode(xsl))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would rather suggest to edit `income.xml` and add `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ENG_Template.xsl"?>` before the root element of the XML, then you don't need any Javascript and you can load the XML directly into the browser which applies the referenced XSLT.

Comment: I have over 1000 xml files that has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./ReportViewer.aspx?XSL=1"?>`